# full width div in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Why is my bottom border in the inside div not full width?

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-2 bg-light mh-100">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center border-bottom w-100">
                    <img class="my-3" src="img/img.png" alt="" srcset="" style="height:18px; width:110px;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-10 bg-dark mh-100">
                <p>sfsdfsdfsd</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "why my border bottom in inside div is not full width?"

Because Bootstrap columns have padding. Use `p-0` (padding:0) to remove it.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-2 bg-light mh-100 p-0">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center border-bottom w-100">
                <img class="my-3" src="img/avayadak.png" alt="" srcset="" style="height:18px; width:110px;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-10 bg-dark mh-100">
            <p>sfsdfsdfsd</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/SVpElPIXAw

**Full width edge-to-edge layout in Bootstrap 4**

As [explained in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#no-gutters), zero out container-fluid padding (px-0), and use `no-gutters` on the row..

```
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-12">
            (edge-to-edge content)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also the container-fluid can be simply removed when using .row.no-gutters.

[Bootstrap 4 Full Width](https://www.codeply.com/p/M9DL3AvEys/bootstrap-full-width)

Answer (score 4):

According to bootstrap 4 documentation:

> Need an edge-to-edge design? Drop the parent .container or
>   .container-fluid.

[Bootstrap 4 No Gutters docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#no-gutters)

So:

```
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-2 bg-light mh-100">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center border-bottom w-100">
                <img class="my-3" src="img/img.png" alt="" srcset="" style="height:18px; width:110px;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-10 bg-dark mh-100">
            <p>sfsdfsdfsd</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution :

```css
.full-width {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-width">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.